# CloudFront - access Website by using CDN IP address instead of DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I configured CDN in front of my website. Everything works well when you access the website via my custom DNS or CDN DNS. My problem is when I want to use an IP instead of DNS.

When I do a nslookup on my CDN DNS name, I get a list of IP's. If I grab one IP address from there and try to access the website, I get a 403 Forbidden request.

Why is CDN only accepting DNS request and not IP's?

What if I have a proxy in front of my CDN and try to access my website by using the proxy IP, how can I access the website using the proxy IP which points to CDN?

It's a wired requirement and time consuming, I've been looking for the correct answer. No one seems to show a solution.

Cheers!

Comment: The same CDN is serving many customer's websites, so they have to rely on the hostname in order to know which content to serve. Also their infrastructure is very dynamic, their IP addresses change, that is why they always ask you to point your DNS domain name using CNAME/alias record to one of their (sub)domains, never to fixed IP address.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is CDN only accepting DNS request and not IP's?

CloudFront is not designed to work this way.  It is a massive, globally-distributed system.  When you look up the IP addresses of your CloudFront distribution, you are receiving the list of addresses where CloudFront expects to receive traffic:

- for your web site, and
- for potentially hundreds or thousands of other sites, and
- from browsers in the same geographic area as you

You need a way to identify *which* distribution you expect CloudFront to use when processing your request.

In HTTP mode, this uses the `Host:` HTTP header, sent by the browser.  In HTTPS mode, this uses the TLS SNI value and the `Host:` header.

If you were using a proxy to access CloudFront, you would need for the proxy to inject a `Host` header for HTTP and to set the SNI correctly, too, for HTTPS.

In HAProxy, for example, set the host header, overwriting any such header that's already present.

```
http-request set-header Host dzczcexample.cloudfront.net
```

Of course, you might use any one of the Alternate Domain Name values configured for your distribution, as well.

For SNI:

```
backend my-cloudfront-backend
    server my-cloudfront dzczcexample.cloudfront.net:443 ssl verify none sni str(dzczcexample.cloudfront.net)
```

(Source: https://serverfault.com/a/830327/153161)

But this is only a minimum baseline working configuration, because CloudFront has features that this simple setup overlooks.

As noted above, CloudFront is returning a list of IP addresses that should be used to access (1) your site, (2) from where you are, (3) right now.  The list of addresses can and will vary.  CloudFront appears to be able to dynamically manage and distribute its workload and mitigate DDoS by moving traffic from one set of servers to another, from one edge location to another, etc., by modifying the DNS responses... so your proxy needs to be using the multiple addresses returned, and needs to be refreshing its DNS values so that it always connects to where CloudFront wishes for it to connect, for optimum behavior and performance.

Also, don't overlook the fact that a proxy server will connect to CloudFront via an edge near the proxy, not near the browser, so this is not something you would routinely use in production, though it absolutely does have some valid use cases.  (I have used HAProxy on both sides of CloudFront for several years, for certain applications -- some of which have now been obviated by Lambda@Edge, but I digress).

> It's a wired [weird?] requirement

Not really.  Name-based virtual hosting has been the standard practice for many years.  It is -- in my opinion -- almost an accident of history that when you set up a web server, it will commonly respond on the IP address in the `Host` header, as well.  A well-configured web server will not do this -- if you (the web browser) don't know what host you are asking for and are just sending a request to my IP, then I (the web server) should tell you I have no idea what you want from me, because you are more likely than not to be arriving for malicious reasons, or benign but annoying reasons (scanning), or as the result of a misconfiguration.  You also don't want search engine spiders finding your content at an IP address.  Bad for listings, bad for SEO.

Answer (score -1):

The problem I have with this proxy is I cannot configure the headers. I was thinking to add another proxy where I have control and then modify the headers with the values I want. But this is not really a good solution, is like jumping from one proxy to another.

I think I should rely more on DNS and hostnames, rather than IP's. Which is fine with me, I prefer using proper DNS name.

Thanks for your thorough explanation, you clarify a lot of things.